# How to combine all files into one file, as I want

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, sh

There are 1000 txt files in a folder.
The contents of the files are as follows:

```
("a1", "b1")
```

I want to combine all the files into one file. However, I have to separate the contents of each file with commas.

```
("a1", "b1"), ("a2", "b2")
```

Then I need to add a fixed text at the beginning and end as below.

```
START ("a1", "b1"), ("a2", "b2") END
```

However, as long as the number of files to be added is 100, it should create a new line.

Example:

```
START ("a1", "b1"), ("a2", "b2") ... END
...
START ("a900", "b900"), ("a901", "b901") ... END
```

The values ​​I have given in the example are just examples to explain in a simpler way.

I need to write this as a bash script to run on the server.

I was able to do something like the following, but I don't think it's good code.
Unfortunately I was unable to create a new line in every 100 files.

```
echo "START " > all.txt
cat *.txt >> all.txt
sed -i 's/)(/),(/g' all.txt
echo " END" >> all.txt
```

Frankly, I need your help as it is a very complex code for me.

I am open to your valuable comments and suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an attempt to do it with an awk one-liner (I used 3 columns for easier demonstration):

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "START "} NR == 1 { printf "%s", $0; next} NR % 3 == 1 { printf " END\nSTART %s", $0;next}  {printf ", %s", $0} END { print " END"}' file*

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "START "} NR == 1 { printf "%s", $0; next} NR % 3 == 1 { printf " END\nSTART %s", $0;next}  {printf ", %s", $0} END { print " END"}' file*
START (10,  0), (11,  0), (12,  0) END
START (13,  0), (14,  0), (15,  0) END
START (16,  0), (17,  0), (18,  0) END
START (19,  0), (20,  0), (21,  0) END
START (22,  0), (23,  0), (24,  0) END
START (25,  0), (26,  0), (27,  0) END
START (28,  0), (29,  0), (30,  0) END
START (31,  0), (32,  0), (33,  0) END
START (34,  0), (35,  0), (36,  0) END
START (37,  0), (38,  0), (39,  0) END
START (40,  0), (41,  0), (42,  0) END
START (43,  0), (44,  0), (45,  0) END
START (46,  0), (47,  0), (48,  0) END
START (49,  0), (50,  0), (51,  0) END
START (52,  0), (53,  0), (54,  0) END
START (55,  0), (56,  0), (57,  0) END
START (58,  0), (59,  0), (60,  0) END
START (61,  0), (62,  0), (63,  0) END
START (64,  0), (65,  0), (66,  0) END
START (67,  0), (68,  0), (69,  0) END
START (70,  0), (71,  0), (72,  0) END
START (73,  0), (74,  0), (75,  0) END
START (76,  0), (77,  0), (78,  0) END
START (79,  0), (80,  0), (81,  0) END
START (82,  0), (83,  0), (84,  0) END
START (85,  0), (86,  0), (87,  0) END
START (88,  0), (89,  0), (90,  0) END
START (91,  0), (92,  0), (93,  0) END
START (94,  0), (95,  0), (96,  0) END
START (97,  0), (98,  0), (99,  0) END
```

Or in a more readable format:

```
BEGIN { printf "START " }
NR == 1 { printf "%s", $0; next }
NR % 3 == 1 { printf " END\nSTART %s", $0; next }
{ printf ", %s", $0 }
END { print " END" }
```

If you really have a large list of files, you could get `argument list too long` error. To fix this, use `xargs` instead.

```sh
echo file* | xargs awk '......' > joined
```

This looks like it would have the same issue, but because `echo` is builtin to `bash`, it is not bound by the argument length limitation.

Comment: The code works fine, there is only one bug.
File 2 is read twice.
START 2, 2, 1 END
START 3, 4, 5 END
START 6, 7 END

Comment: @user14296498: Right, the final check should be `NR > 1`, updated the answer

Comment: There was no problem with 1k file. But when I try on 1 million files it gives this error.
awk: argument list too long
Can we find a solution on this issue?

Comment: @user14296498: That can be fixed with `xargs`, see the edit in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (untested) should do it:

```
awk '
    { rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec ", ") $0 }
    (NR%100) == 0 {
        print "START", rec, "END"
        rec = ""
    }
' *
```

Comment: I tried your example and it worked. Your code is cleaner, thank you. I think I'll update it with this one.

Comment: I noticed a mistake. It will not work if the number of files is less than 100.

Comment: @user14296498 that's not a mistake. In your question you said you wanted `as long as the number of files to be added is 100, it should create a new line.` so that is what the script is designed to do. You didn't say anything about handling fewer than 100 or a total that's not a multiple of 100. If you need to handle any situations like that then update your question to at least state your requirements for that as there are a couple of different options for what to do in that situation (print the subset, not print from the front, or not print from the back come to mind).

Comment: @user14296498: It can be easily fixed though, just add `END{ print "START", rec, "END" }` before the single bracket on the last line. OR `END {if (NR%100 != 0) { print "START", rec, "END" }}`

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for it in shell - but technically, if you prepend the Python solution with a `python -c "`, it is shell, is not it? [wink]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os

contents = []

with ('all.txt', 'wt') as output:
    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
       if filename == 'all.txt': continue
       contents.append(open(filename).read().strip())
       if len(contents) >= 100:
           output.write(f'''START {', '.join(contents)} END\n''')
           contents = []
    output.write(f'''START {', '.join(contents)} END\n''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash variant

```
n=1; while read -r line; do
    ((n==1))  &&   printf 'start '
                   printf "$line"
    ((n>=10)) && { printf ' end\n';   n=1  ; } \
              || { printf ', '    ; ((n++)); }
done < <(cat file*)
```